# Holomorphic fucntion with $|f(z)|\leq \log |z|$ for all $z\in D_2(0)^c$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic with $|f(z)|\leq \log |z|$ for all $z\in D_2(0)^c$. Show that $f$ is constant.

What I have:
Using the standard estimation and Cauchy's integral formula for the taylor series I have:

$\displaystyle |a_{n}|=\frac{1}{n!}|f^{(n+1)}(z)|=\frac{1}{n!}|\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+2}}d\zeta|\leq\frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi n!}2\pi R\frac{\log|z|}{(R/2)^{n+2}}=\frac{(n+1)2^{n+2}}{R^{n+1}}\log|z|$

So I would obtain $|a_n|\to0$ as $R\to\infty$ implying that $f\equiv 0$. Is there an error somewhere? I'm fairly sure the proof works with the tools I used but I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: $D_2(0)^c$ is the complement of the disc with center $0$ and radius $2$?

Comment: $$a_n = \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0),$$ not $f^{(n+1)}(0)$. You get $a_n = 0$ for $n\geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes !

For $R>2$ we have, since $|f(\zeta)| \le \log |R| $ for $| \zeta| =R$,

$|a_{n}| \le \frac{\log |R|}{R^n}$.

Comment: Okay. Let's say we have $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$. In general I can conclude $\displaystyle |a_{n}|=\frac{1}{n!}|f^{(n)}(z)|=\frac{1}{n!}|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta|\leq R\frac{|g(R)|}{(R/2)^{n+1}}$